# Sharing an IDE Ruby app with employers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, ide

I'm a student trying to share a Ruby application I created over the summer.
Is there a way to convert an application created in an IDE (C9) to a server such as AWS? I want to be able to share my application with employers at any time. But I'm not sure what type of service to use with AWS. I've explored Lamda and web hosting but I'm not sure that they're the right services. Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: Do you want to share the source-code or the running application? if source-code, go with `github` or other another public & free service for versioning.

Comment: I want to share a running application. I can run the c9 server but I don't think it stays running for long periods.

Comment: You can take a look at Heroku, I never really used it but I recall that their free version is acceptable for this kind of needs.

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks.

Comment: The correct terminology here is "I want to deploy a Ruby application" and "Is there a way to deploy to a server such as AWS?" Most Ruby projects use something like [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com) to help with deployment. Heroku is an interesting option that's really easy to get started with, and also worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really broad question that basically reduces to "It works on Cloud9. How can I make it work somewhere else in the cloud?". I'm assuming this will eventually be marked closed for this reason, but here's my short answer.

At the moment, there is no "migrate" button in Cloud9 that allows you to port over your environment into a different service. Because of this, you'll need to capture key details about your operating system, dependencies, and runtime requirements and use those to search out suitable service in AWS that meets those requirements.

Because you're describing a non-production application with (I imagine) forgiving technical requirements, I would start by asking your employer which runtimes they prefer and go from there. Good luck!